# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass in nested form using check_box_tag to create associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, has-many-through, null

I keep getting this error when trying to add nested attributes via checkboxes:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

the error is in the controller on this line
:
"@food_rule = @meal.food_rules.build(params[:food_rule][:restriction_ids])"

My models uses has_many through

```
 class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :food_rules, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :restrictions, :through => :food_rules,
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :food_rules, allow_destroy: true

 end

 class FoodRule < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :meal
  belongs_to :restriction
 end

  class Restriction < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :food_rules, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :meals, :through => :food_rules,
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :food_rules, allow_destroy: true

 end
```

This is my MealsController
my "add_restrictions" method that adds a :meal_restrictions record via checkboxes

```
 def add_restrictions
      @diet = Restriction.k1.order(:name)

      @meal = Meal.find(params[:m])
      params[:restriction][:restriction_id] ||= []
      @food_rule = @meal.food_rule.build(params[:food_rules][:restriction_ids])

     respond_to do |format|
       if  @food_rules.save
       format.html { redirect_to t1s3_path(:m => @meal.id ) , 
         notice: 'Success! You added meal restrictions!' }
       format.json {}
       else
        format.html { render :new,  notice: 'oops....try again'}
        format.json { render json: @template.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
    end
```

What's being submitted

```
   {"utf8"=>"✓",
   "_method"=>"patch",
  "authenticity_token"=>"bVZ4dhVJKTkI43TQGqESINNwkBSswh3h75ofbRBlTwQ=",
  "restriction"=>{"restriction_ids"=>["",
  "1",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "7",
  "",
  ""]},
  "commit"=>"Next",
  "m"=>"234"}
```

this is my form:

```
   <%= form_for @meal, url: add_restrictions_path(:m => @meal.id) do |f| %>
     <div class="row" >
      <div class="form ">
       <div class="form-group">     
             <% @diet.each do |restriction| %>
               <%= hidden_field_tag "meal[restriction_ids][]", nil %>
                 <%= check_box_tag "meal[restriction_ids][]", restriction.id,   
                   @meal.restriction_ids.include?(restriction.id) %> 
                   <%= label_tag dom_id(restriction), restriction.name %><br>
    <!-- checkbox --><% end %>

        </div><!-- form group -->
         <%= f.submit 'Next' %>  
         <% end %> 
        </div> 
      </div>
```

**EDIT: Progress**

```
   I changed @food_rule = @meal.food_rule.build(params[:food_rules][:restriction_ids]) to @food_rule = @meal.food_rule.build(params[:food_rule][:restriction_ids]), (removed an s), but it's still throwing the same error.
```

**I changed the model MealRestrictions to FoodRules....because it was getting to confusing to figure out this problem with a through name. Thus...any comment that has :meal_restrictions should read :food_rules**

Comment: In which file and on which line do you get the error? Which line is that in the code you show here?

Comment: MealController, this line "      @meal_restriction = @meal.meal_restrictions.build(params[:meal_restrictions][:restriction_ids])
"

Comment: What happens if you change that to `@meal_restriction = @meal.meal_restrictions.build(params[:meal_restrictions])`. The error could also be caused by some mismatch between the naming conventions of Rails and your `restriction` form elements. See [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) where they mention some naming conventions of the posted parameters when using `fields_for`. You might want to change your form code uo use `fields_for`.

Comment: when I do that meal_restriction.meal_id is recorded, but meal_restriction.restriction_id is not.  I've had this problem before and that's what I was trying to fix with the above code.  I haven't named any of the reference columns anything weird....just parent_id.  I'll check out those docs and try fields_for

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere change this line and try `@meal_restriction = @meal.meal_restrictions.build(params[:meal_restriction][:restriction_ids])`

Comment: Change it to what? That's how I have it @anusha

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere No you have plura for params[:meal_restrictions] change to singular params[:meal_restriction] and try

Comment: Ah! Sorry @anusha ... I checked again and saw th "s"

Comment: Thank you @anusha, but if I change it to what you suggest, it still throws "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" ...thought I think you are right. I just don't know why it's throwing this error.

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere By seeing the url parameters i think it is taking as `restriction` but not `meal_restriction` so try once using `params[:restriction][:restrition_ids] `

Comment: @anusha when I try `params[:restriction][:restriction_id] ||= []` it throws a nil error...when I try `params[:restricted][:restriction_id] ||= []` it reads that fine, but then says it "undefined method 'restricted' on this line '     `restricted = project.restricted.build(params[:restricted][:restriction_ids])`
' and...through fiddling, I know it means 'project.restricted' not `[:restricted]` ....`restricteds` doesn't work either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63825/discussion-between-anusha-and-nothingtoseehere).

Comment: "restriction_ids"=>["",
  "1",] there are so many blank fields
try
restriction_id.reject! { |r| r.empty? }

Comment: where do I put that @argentum47 ?

Comment: before you access it, which in this case is before @food_rule.
you can actually install the pry gem. write `binding.pry` in the first line of the method, thereby setting a break_point, and then in the console you can try and see where the error is.